# How to make flutter web size like app size

Tags: flutter, web, size

I am developing a flutter app and try to run it on web too. How do you make the size of a web app like a phone app? I saw some web app has the fixed size of phone app like following;https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J36E.jpg

Comment: Can you please tell me if you get success to achieve UI and if yes then kindly share your idea for how to achieve this Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make it stay in a 16:9 ratio but will scale everything down if needed.

```
FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
    child: Container(
        width: 0.5625*height,
        height: height,
        child: Container(),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Hi, When I tried your code to wrap Scaffold of a page, an error was thrown saying 'RenderInkFeatures object was given an infinite size during layout.' What can be done?

Comment: For me it worked. Can you show your code or atleast the most relevant parts of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I developed a flutter package to handle this for you: https://pub.dev/packages/center_the_widgets

You can use it just like this:

```
 return CenterTheWidgets(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: const Text('Hi!'),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

Adaptive and responsive can be viewed as separate dimensions of a flutter app: you can have an adaptive app that is not responsive or vice versa. And, of course, an app can be both or neither.
You can follow the official docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive