# How to make Flutter web and desktop app look exactly the same scale

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-desktop

Flutter widgets look way bigger in Chrome compared to app run on a desktop (in my case on Linux). I'd like to either scale down web or scale up desktop app to make all the widgets look exactly the same.

I've already tried setting `visualDensity` or using `Transform.scale()` wrapper but both don't solve the problem. I know I can add a const ratio (different for web and desktop) and multiply every width, height, text size etc. by that value, but I feel there must be a simpler solution.

Take a look at web (left) and desktop (right)

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this package: https://pub.dev/packages/sizer

Comment: @Uni it's a similar solution to the one I mentioned with multiplying every size by a specified ratio. I'm looking for something more generic, something that doesn't require changes to every place sizes are used

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "something that doesn't require changes to every place sizes are used". Are you looking for something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYDVcriKjsw

Comment: @Uni no. I just want to have Container(width: 50, height: 50) look exactly the same on web & desktop. I don't want to do any additional calculations like "width: 50 * ratio" to make it look the same

Comment: I don't think thats possible. You need to apply calculations to make it look the same. Screen sizes, density, and ratio differs from one device to another.

Comment: both screenshots are from the same computer box?

Comment: @pskink yes. Desktop app and a browser side by side

Comment: and the browser is a Google chrome with the default 100% zoom? what if user use Firefox for example? or any other supported browser? I think it is a "tilting at windmills"

Comment: @pskink it's at 100%. Opened the webpage in Opera browser and it looks exactly the same as in Chrome. You can try to open default project in browser and as a desktop app and see the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make flutter web size like app size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64183766/how-to-make-flutter-web-size-like-app-size)